# How to calculate CRC on 9 or 17 bits?

Tags: c++, embedded, microcontroller, spi, crc

the device I'm using requires me (or a library) to calculate a **CRC-7 on a 17 bit word**.

This word might be: 1010 1010 0101 0101 1 (17 Bits)

Most libraries only take whole bytes as input. Is there a way to, idk, shift the word to make it compatible with standard calculation methods?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It probably depends on the library.

Comment: Right now I'm using boost's crc. I can easily tell it to use a CRC-7. But its input is a uint8_t array, so I can only work on a byte-level. The CRC it produces does not fit the one expected by the device (obviously because boost works on 24 bit while the device calculates on 17 bit).

Comment: Why not use padding?

Comment: If this is used to ensure noise stability over a communication channel, I think zero padding right (left shift) or left to the next byte boundary should be fine. If the device uses a specified method, you obviously have to use that.

Comment: Like this?

1010 1010 0101 0101 1 (17 Bit)

0000 0001 0101 0100 1010 1011 (24 Bit with 7 Bit Padding)

Comment: The devices just specifies that the CRC-7 is calculated over the 16 bit data + an appended '1'. That's all it says unfortunately.

Comment: I think you will have to pass on a number of bits parameter to the CRC function. But since this is such a small amount of data, might as well unroll the whole CRC algorithm, no loops, just repeated XOR and store results 17 times.

Comment: The left padding seems to work for now - thanks :)

Comment: You may want to have a look at unions for bit staffing.